# Removing a row from a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using to add a some rows using javascript. I was able to achieve that using:

```
$('#order_basket > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><b>'+Book+
             '</td><td>'+Type+'</td><td>'+'<span onclick="removeRow()"'+
             'class="label label-important">Remove</span></td></tr>');      
        return false;
});
```

Now i also want to be able to remove that row using javascript too. In the able code i have a label named as Remove which is calling another function in my javascript that is being used to remove the selected row. However i am unable to achieve that. The code i am using to remove the row is:

```
function removeRow() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: How are you calling the `removeRow` function ?

Comment: using onclick, its there in the first block of code `<span onclick="removeRow()"`.

Comment: Didn't this work? : [Delete a table row with javascript / jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922066/delete-a-table-row-with-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @Namit: Ok got you, see my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass `this` inside the `onclick` event as follows:

```
'<span onclick="removeRow(this)"'
```

And change the function to:

```
function removeRow(row) {
    $(row).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Instead of passing the event as an attribute via the HTML, you can also use:

```
        $('#order_basket > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><b>' + Book +
             '</td><td>'+Type+'</td><td>'+'<span'+
             'class="label label-important remove">Remove</span></td></tr>');      
        return false;
});

$('#order_basket > tbody:last').on('click', 'span.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Works if i change the `$(this).closest('row').remove();` to `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`